# Обмен сообщениями между потоками

Tags: c#

у меня есть сервер, который создает отдельный поток для каждого клиента

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Threading;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Test
{
    class Server
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IPHostEntry ipHost = Dns.GetHostEntry("192.168.1.52");
            IPAddress ipAddr = ipHost.AddressList[0];
            IPEndPoint ipEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddr, 11111);

            Socket sListener = new Socket(ipAddr.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            int maxClients = 10;

            try
            {
                sListener.Bind(ipEndPoint);
                sListener.Listen(maxClients);
                Console.WriteLine("[Info] Ожидаем соединение через порт {0}", ipEndPoint);

                while (true)
                {
                    Socket handler = sListener.Accept();
                    IPAddress client_ip = ((IPEndPoint)handler.RemoteEndPoint).Address;
                    ClientObject clientObject = new ClientObject(handler);

                    // создаем новый поток для обслуживания нового клиента
                    Thread clientThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(clientObject.Process));
                    clientThread.Start();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            }
            finally
            {
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Как можно называть каждый поток при создании своим именем (например образно Sasha, Masha, Dasha) и из потока Sasha в поток Masha передать данные через сокет?
Вот сам поток

```
using System.Text;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;

namespace Squirrels
{
    public class ClientObject
    {
        public Socket handler;
        public ClientObject(Socket socket)
        {
            handler = socket;
        }

        public void Process()
        {
            try
            {
                byte[] bytes;
                int bytesRec;

                while (true)
                {
                    bytes = new byte[1024];
                    bytesRec = handler.Receive(bytes);

                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            }
            finally
            {
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: на сколько знаю - handle это  идентификатор для сокета. Вы можете его запоминать. Ну и словари в помощь для создания вашего идентификатора.

Comment: @Виталий Шебаниц а как отправить информацию из одного потока в другой?

Comment: А для чего? Возможно подойдет просто запуск потока с параметрами?